# Is my tolerance stackup correct?

Tags: tolerance, drawings

Major questions:

- Are 0.028 locating tolerances divided by two for left/right shift?
- Do overall drawing tolerances apply to a thru hole with a locating tolerance of 0.028 (max material condition)?
- If a part is dimensioned off a theoretical center, does the overall dimension apply to the stackup?

[image: Image of drawings & questions]

Comment: Is the purpose of your analysis to determine whether all four holes line up with the respective inserts at the same time? If so, an important feature is the major diameter of the screw that goes into the insert since that's the nominal diameter of the feature you want to maintain clearance for.

Comment: First of all, that drawing is invalid. The distance between the holes should be basic dimensions as the feature control frames handle the tolerance of position of the holes and inserts. Then try again...

Comment: Yes, those are basic dimensions. I'm trying to 1.) dimension the drawing correctly so the stackup is as perfectly centered as possible and 2.) figure out how big the orange oversized hole has to be for the tolerance stackup so the part can always be assembled to the next higher assembly

Comment: I made a 2nd attempt here. How does this look? https://imgur.com/MLI7EDu